# Can we change browser url but not redirect after post back?

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, query-string, redirect

**Context**: 
I  have a page to which I navigate from a link in a gridview in a different page.

Here's the url for the current page .

http://somedomain.com/timesheet.aspx?**tskey=0**&emplid=10068323&pnbr=10053911&pbdate=03182012&pedate=03312012&emprcd=0&scheduletype=BW

On this page , I make some edits and hit Save button .It is submitted to database which generates **tskey** value for me. tskey is a query string variable.

Now that I have the tskey value after I saved the current page, can I change the current page's url to update the  **tskey** value at the end of Save click event without redirecting.

Comment: To accomplish what? As in, if you already have the value, why do you need to stuff it in the querystring?

Comment: In this case after the tskey is generated, if the user happens to reload the page with tskey=0 as query string value, it throws an exception.

So thought if it is possible to update the tskey value on postback but not by redirecting.

The reason , I don't want to use a redirect is that after postback I get an acknowledgement message about the save which doesn't happen on a redirect .

Please correct me if what I m' asking seems illogical ...

Comment: It sounds like your real problem is "why does user refresh cause an exception"... fix that (like possibly checking if value exists before insert) and then you won't need kludgey work-arounds.

Comment: What you are asking is not illogical. Not wanting the user to re-post form is common problem. It is just that your approach is incorrect. You need to fix why user-refresh is causing exception... you can probably start by removing `tskey=0` from query string (since it seems like you have a querystring variable just to "not" have a value) and moving forward from there.

Comment: That's correct , now I realized that it is always possible for the user to manipulate the querystring and re load.

Now I have it fixed after handling such exceptions.

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about what you're asking:

1. You want the browser to post to some URL, which will generate some value, and return some kind of HTTP response.
2. ???
3. Browser now points to a different URL.

Step two has to change the URL from one value to another.  Whether you do that with a server redirect or JavaScript to change document.location, the browser has to get the contents of that new page and render it.

If you want to do a postback to the new URL, that's pretty easy to do from JavaScript, just use `Page.ClientScript.GetCallbackEventReference()` to put the function in your page, and then invoke it.  Of course this will cause the page to reload the new response, but there's no way around that.  If that doesn't do exactly what you want, you'll have to render and post the form yourself.

It sounds like a fair amount of unnecessary work.  Are you sure you need to do this?

Comment: Note that it has to render the "new page", even if the contents of the "new page" are identical to the contents of the "old page".

Comment: Exactly.  It might be *your intention* that the pages be identical, but the browser has no way of knowing that they are at all related.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I don't want to use redirect. I want it to be a regular postback but in load or some event , i want to update the  querystring in the url just like we do with text box.

Not sure if it is possible though.

Let me know..

Comment: In short , I want it to render as expected after post back except at the end of this post back , I want the url to update but not redirect

Comment: The URL is not part of the page and can't be updated in that way.  It represents the resource that generated the contents of the page.  It doesn't make sense to change the URL without also reloading the page, no matter if this is done with a redirect, a postback, changing window.location, etc.